# Parsing XML data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, file, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting this error on my chrome console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Document> has no method 'getElementByTagName' Calendar.html:160
parseXML Calendar.html:160
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange`

My XML comes out as null.

I'm new to XML so I'm, not sure what this means. I have validated my XML and it only gives me one warning for charset "text/xml" but that shouldnt be what is causing it. Here is what I have:

Button handler to get XML data.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="getServerData('Event.XML','divData')" value="Serve Me" />
```

Then here goes.

```
function parseXML(xmlData){
var eventYear = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("year");
var eventMonth = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("month");
var eventDay = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("day");
var eventHour = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("hours");
var eventMinute = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("minutes");
var eventTitle = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("title");

}
function getServerData(dataIN,tagOUT)
{
    var dataOutput=document.getElementById(tagOUT)
    //alert(dataIN)
    //alert(tagOUT)
   if(XMLHttpRequestObject) 
   {
       XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataIN);
       XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) 
            {
                var xmlResponse = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;

                parseXML(xmlResponse);
                dataOutput.innerHTML = xmlResponse;

            }
        }
        XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
    }
}
```

Heres XML sample:

```
<event>
      <date>
        <year>2013</year>
        <month>2</month>
        <day>4</day>
      </date>
      <time>
          <start>
            <hours>12</hours>
            <minutes>00</minutes>
          </start>
          <end>
            <hours>2</hours>
            <minutes>30</minutes>
          </end>
      </time>
    <title>Party</title>    
  </event>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the method is `getElementsByTagName` not `getElementByTagName` notice the `s`.

Comment: you wrote it before I could :)

Comment: Alright so when `getServerData()` returning `[object document]` is correct?

Comment: @GivenPie what do you want to put in `dataOutput`?

Comment: I wanted to see my xml data in dataOutput. Which i will give variables after to put into an array.

Comment: @GivenPie Try `dataOutput.appendChild(document.createTextNode(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText));`